# C# - Tier Separation - How to use these delegates?

Tags: c#

Here's the relevant code:

**ClickMeGame.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public class ClickMeGame
{
    public OnClickMe onClickMeCallback;

    public int score;

    public ClickMeGame()
    {
        score = 0;
    }

    private void IncrementScore()
    {
        score++;
    }
}
}
```

**ClickMeCallBackDefinitions.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public delegate void OnClickMe();
}
```

**MainWindow.cs** (Windows Form)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ClassLibrary;

namespace ClickMe
{
    public partial class mainWindow : Form
{
    private ClickMeGame game;

    public mainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        game = new ClickMeGame();
        game.onClickMeCallback = clickMeButton_Click();

    }

    private void clickMeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateUI(); 
    }

    private void UpdateUI()
    {
        scoreLabel.Text = string.Format("The score is: {0}", game.score);
    }
}
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is, when the user clicks a button present on the form, I want a label on the form to update with the game score which increments with every click.

I'm learning about/want to be able to do this with delegates in that I want to separate the project into 2 tiers; Presenation and Logic. I know it's unnecessary to do so, but I'd like to make it such that when you click the button, the Windows Form receives information about the game score via delegates/callback methods. I'm unsure how to do this, but I tried making the callback definition and referencing it, but I'm lost from there.

Comment: Just write `game.onClickMeCallback = UpdateUi;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the UI button uses the click event clickMeButton_Click then here you go.

```
public partial class mainWindow : Form
{
    private ClickMeGame game;

    public mainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        game = new ClickMeGame();
        game.onClickMeCallback = param => UpdateUI();

    }

    private void clickMeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        game.onClickMeCallback.Invoke(); 
    }

    private void UpdateUI()
    {
        scoreLabel.Text = string.Format("The score is: {0}", game.score);
    }
}
```